# Scraping multiple (market index) sites with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

Im developing the following code to scrape financial data from a specific website source.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


urls = ['https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials/cash-flow',
        'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials/cash-flow/quarter',
        'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/MSFT/financials/cash-flow',
        'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/MSFT/financials/cash-flow/quarter']


def main(urls):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        goal = []
        for url in urls:
            r = req.get(url)
            df = pd.read_html(
                r.content, match="Cash Dividends Paid - Total")[0].iloc[[0], 3:6]
            goal.append(df)
        new = pd.concat(goal)
        print(new)


main(urls)
```

Im getting the information that I need.

```
      2017      2018      2019 30-Sep-2019 31-Dec-2019 31-Mar-2020
0  (12.77B)  (13.71B)  (14.12B)         NaN         NaN         NaN
0       NaN       NaN       NaN     (3.48B)     (3.54B)     (3.38B)
0  (11.85B)   (12.7B)  (13.81B)         NaN         NaN         NaN
0       NaN       NaN       NaN     (3.51B)     (3.89B)     (3.88B)
```

I need to scrape at least 20 companies (from the same source).
The URL is basically the same except for one element (I will call it **index**)

```
https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/' + index + '/financials/cash-flow'
```

Is there a way to add a variable called **Index**

And iterate using the variable **Index**

Something like:

```
   import requests
   import pandas as pd
   Index = 'MSFT, AAPL'
```

and

```
urls = ['https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/' + Index + '/financials/cash-flow',
'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/' + Index + '/financials/cash-flow/quarter']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just straightforward solution, you can use loop inside loop and string formatting to construct the required URL.

For example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

indexes = 'aapl', 'MSFT', 'F'

def main(indexes):
    urls = ['https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/{index}/financials/cash-flow',
            'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/{index}/financials/cash-flow/quarter']
    goal = []

    with requests.Session() as req:
        for index in indexes:
            for url in urls:
                url = url.format(index=index)
                print('Processing url', url)
                r = req.get(url)
                df = pd.read_html(
                    r.content, match="Cash Dividends Paid - Total")[0].iloc[[0], 3:6]
                goal.append(df)
        new = pd.concat(goal)
        print(new)

main(indexes)
```

Prints:

```
Processing url https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials/cash-flow
Processing url https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/financials/cash-flow/quarter
Processing url https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/MSFT/financials/cash-flow
Processing url https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/MSFT/financials/cash-flow/quarter
Processing url https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/F/financials/cash-flow
Processing url https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/F/financials/cash-flow/quarter
       2017      2018      2019 30-Sep-2019 31-Dec-2019 31-Mar-2020
0  (12.77B)  (13.71B)  (14.12B)         NaN         NaN         NaN
0       NaN       NaN       NaN     (3.48B)     (3.54B)     (3.38B)
0  (11.85B)   (12.7B)  (13.81B)         NaN         NaN         NaN
0       NaN       NaN       NaN     (3.51B)     (3.89B)     (3.88B)
0   (2.58B)   (2.91B)   (2.39B)         NaN         NaN         NaN
0       NaN       NaN       NaN      (598M)      (595M)      (596M)
```